# Delete row when checkbox previously selected is deselected

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I have a table naming related_products,

Where
`products_id` is the main product.

and `related_products_ids` consist of product ids related to the main product.

```
--------------------------------------------
|   products_id   |   related_products_ids |
| -----------------------------------------
|    1            |   2                 |
| -----------------------------------------
|    1            |   4                 |
| -----------------------------------------
|    1            |   3                 |
-------------------------------------------
```

I have checkboxes,

```
<input value="2" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category2"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 2
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category3"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 3
<input value="4" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category3"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 4
```

The checkboxes are generated by php,

```
<?php
echo '<ul id="categorychecklist" class="list:category categorychecklist form-no-clear">';
  global $wpdb;
  $sql = "SELECT related_products_ids FROM ".TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS." where products_id = '" . (int)$HTTP_GET_VARS['pID']."'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $rps = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $rps[]=$row["related_products_ids"];     
   }
$rp_sql = "select products_id, products_name from ".TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION." where products_id !='" . (int)$HTTP_GET_VARS['pID']."' order by products_name";
  $rp_1 = mysql_query($rp_sql);
  while($rp_2 = mysql_fetch_array($rp_1)) {
    $checked = '';
    if (in_array($rp_2['products_id'], $rps)) $checked = " checked";
    echo "<li id=\"category-".$rp_2['products_id']."\" class=\"popular-category\"><label class=\"selectit\"><input value=\"".$rp_2['products_id']."\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"rp_product[]\" class=\"rp_item\"" . $checked . "> <span>".$rp_2['products_name']."</span></label></li>";
  }
mysql_free_result($rp_1);
echo '</ul></div></div>';
?>
```

And i use this code to save the checked checkboxes to the `related_products` table,

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['rp_product']); $i++)
 {
  $check_val1 .= $_POST['rp_product'][$i] .","; //gather data
 }
$check_val = trim($check_val1, ',');  //clean last ,
unset($check_val1); //flush

$insert_rp_ids1 = explode(',', $check_val);

foreach($insert_rp_ids1 as $id){ 
   $rps_each2 = array('products_id' => $products_id, 'related_products_ids' => $id);
   $wpdb->insert(TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS, $rps_each2);
}
```

What i want is to delete a particular id under `related_products_ids` column when the checkbox previously selected is deselected..

Lets say im editing the post where the products_id is `1` and where the `related_products_ids` of it is `2, 3 and 4`.. I deselected the checkbox where the value is `3`(which is on the `related_products_ids`) and after hitting the save button, the value `3` on the `related_products_ids` will be deleted so that current rows now is `2 and 4`. How to do that? I can't think and find a solution for this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic here is that on edit action all related products are repopulated in database. If they are repopulated, then the easiest is to remove them before.

To achieve this, on submit, just before you insert anything to `related_products` table, delete all rows where `products_id` equals `$products_id`. Do this between the two lines in your code:

```
$insert_rp_ids1 = explode(',', $check_val);
```

and

```
foreach($insert_rp_ids1 as $id){
```

In addition, you may consider using transaction or, if not supported by your table, checking if the delete statement succeeded.

Comment: @Ken Can you confirm that currently your script is able to _add_ new entries to `related_products_ids` table? Do you _only_ want to _remove_ deselected entries or by editing posts you want to _add and remove_?

Comment: Sorry. i have found the problem.. its on my sql delete statement.. now it works.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var home = "http://www.mysite.com/";
function performAction(url) {
    document.getElementById("actionFrame").src = (home+url)
}
</script>

<iframe id="actionFrame" width=1 height=1 frameborder=0> </iframe>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="javascript:performAction('index.php?check=1&action=del');" /> Delete row
<input type="checkbox" onClick="javascript:performAction('index.php?check=2&action=del');" /> Delete row
```

All of the variables should be written in PHP when the page is written e.g.:

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($some_array); $i++) {
    $input = "<input type=\"checkbox\""
           . "onClick=\"javascript:performAction('index.php?check=".($i+1)."&action=del');\" />";
    echo $input;
}
```

The PHP page will have something like this to perform the delete:

```
$action = $_GET["action"];
$check = $_GET["check"];

switch ($action) {
    case "del":
        delRow($check);
        break;
}

require_once("database.php"); #file which creates the PDO object $db

function delRow($check) {
    global $db; //because $db is out of scope until we do this
    $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE col_id='?';";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam((int)$check);
    $query->execute();
    $rows = $query->rowCount();
    echo "$rows were deleted.";
}
```

Comment: Thats not what i wanted.. i simple want to delete the value of the deselected checkbox on the mysql table..

Comment: @Ken that wasn't so obvious because then all you needed in your question was the SQL code and not the HTML stuff. Anyway, I included an example for you.